# setting up keras packages and python for machine learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to run a machine learning model that uses keras and tensorflow, and a local dataset of images , but it continued to give me errors in keras packages, here are the errors that gave me :

```
>python train_model.py
```

Error details:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_model.py", line 9, in <module>
    from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
  File "C:\Users\Lapierre06\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\Lapierre06\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import np_utils
  File "C:\Users\Lapierre06\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\np_utils.py", line 64
    return x / np.expand_dims(l2, axis)
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Comment: It's exactly what is says. 'Return' outside function in line 64. I am guessing the return statement is outside the function. Post the code for better clarity.

Comment: check the indentation of return in your function

Comment: now i have this error :  return x / np.expand_dims(l2, axis)
                                      ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: This error is from keras library and I checked the file it is ok, plus you shouldn't edit that directly. What is your keras version?

Comment: I advise you to share your portion of the code where it is being pointed. It is helpful to understand the problem better and many of us can answer faster.